# Getting Error "ORA-01732: data manipulation operation not legal on this view" while deleting from a table in oracle

Tags: oracle, db2

Same query running in Db2 , but in oracle it's giving error.
Please help. thanks in advance.

```
delete from  (SELECT   
     EMP_ID,
     SAL,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY SAL DESC) As RN
FROM     FPM.FACT_PL_BS
WHERE    MEASUREMENT_PERIOD_ID=20170811
AND      SCENARIO_ID=1) A where RN>1}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check documentation [Notes on Updatable Views](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8004.htm#SQLRF54782):

> The view must not contain any of the following constructs:
>
> - A set operator
> - A DISTINCT operator
> - An aggregate or **analytic function**
> - A GROUP BY, ORDER BY, MODEL, CONNECT BY, or START WITH clause
> - A collection expression in a SELECT list
> - A subquery in a SELECT list
> - A subquery designated WITH READ ONLY
> - Joins, with some exceptions, as documented in Oracle Database Administrator's Guide

`ROW_NUMBER` is an [Analytic Function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174), so update is not permitted.

I think this one should work (not tested):

```
delete from FPM.FACT_PL_BS
WHERE ROWID =ANY 
(SELECT   ROW_ID 
FROM 
   (SELECT ROWID as ROW_ID,
     EMP_ID,
     SAL,
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID ORDER BY SAL DESC) As RN
   FROM     FPM.FACT_PL_BS
   WHERE    MEASUREMENT_PERIOD_ID=20170811
      AND      SCENARIO_ID=1)
WHERE RN > 1;
```

or maybe

```
delete from FPM.FACT_PL_BS
WHERE MEASUREMENT_PERIOD_ID=20170811
   AND SCENARIO_ID=1
   AND ROWID <>ALL 
      (select MAX(ROWID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY SAL) OVER (PARTITION BY EMP_ID)
       FROM FPM.FACT_PL_BS)
```